# Why is the knapsack not filled correctly by this R code?

Tags: r, knapsack-problem

Consider the following R-implementation of a knapsack problem (which yields an inefficient runtime behavior on educational purposes).

Given a collection of items with weight 3, 2 and 4 pounds and (in the same order) 7, 4 and 10 Euros value respectively

```
#data:
itemsSize <- c(3, 2, 4)
itemsValue <- c(7, 4, 10)
```

Expected behavior of the following R-function sack() in total: we want a maximum
sum of Euros not violating the capacity limit of the sack. solution
for sack(5) meaning the optimal value of the sack given 5 lb cap limit should
be 11.

```
max <- 0
sack <- function(cap) {
    for (i in (1:length(itemsSize))) {
        if ((space <- (cap - itemsSize[i])) >= 0) {
            if ((rised <- (sack(space) + itemsValue[i])) > max) {
                max <- rised
            }
        }
        return(max)

    }
}
```

Phenomena: a) no matter which item put first, the code only optimizes
regarding that item (tested by changing order of itemsSize along with
order of items value in #data respectively). Expected behaviour would be to
combine items as i counts up.  b) the code doubles items in the sack
(tested by e.g. itemsSize<-c(2,4) and itemsValue<-c(4,10) in #data. Expected behavior would be picking each item at most once.

Overall: a) together with b): the code only packs the first item (and potentially several instances of it) until the sack is full.

Why do these phenomena occur - what did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need to iterate over a lot more parameters. Your sample code doesn't allow you to place two of the same item in the sack, so far as I can tell.  I'd back up and write out the algorithm you want to use, then start coding.  This problem calls for a "tree" algorithm almost for sure.

Comment: @Carl the code "doesn't allow you to place two of the same item in the sack" - that's what I thought as well; however it does, as can be seen in phenomenon b) - where sack(5) becomes 8, which can only be obtained by picking the first item twice

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It is a recursive function `sack` is called once again in the second `if` statement.

Comment: @Statos I'm not sure you want it to be recursive at the given point. You should work through the algorithm as mentioned above.

Comment: @ Carl @Imo thx! This was remorking Python code, which did construct the loop differently; I've overlooked the ever-downdropping i in the recursion. Btw: I want to construct an example in R, which shows students, how dangerous recursion can be - for the actual algorithm I will use something like in MIT's lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFP5VHGHFdk , which is tree-based and beautiful.

Comment: moreover, the code above just represents a heuristics - as unfortunately the first item always gets picked, even when correcting the loop by e.g. introducing a loop paramenter j along with (j:length(itemsSize)) instead of (1:length(itemsSize)) avoiding down-dropping i : the first item will always be picked. Not optimal of course. Maybe this is a "too bad" example, which should not enter my lecture. ;-)